# Not able to get value of all drill down bars in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying fetch bar value from a highchart drill down bar, but i can only fetch from last bar not the remaining onces. 
Example is on this url https://jsfiddle.net/pravisivadasan/j8y21axp/

Can any one help me on this?

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    var protocolNames = ['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5'];
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container_inc',
            type: 'column',
            events: {
                drilldown: function(e) {
                    parentSeriesIndex = e.point.series.index;
                    parentSeriesName = e.point.series.name;
                    chart.setTitle({ text:''});
                    chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({text:''});

                    //chart.xAxis[0].setCategories([], true);

                    chart.yAxis[1].update({
                        labels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        }
                    });
                },
                drillup: function(e) {
                    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(protocolNames, true);
                    chart.xAxis[0].update({labels:{rotation:0}});
                    chart.yAxis[1].update({
                        labels: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        }
                    });  
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Incident - inflow vs Outflow'
        },
        credits: {
        enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: [{
            title: {
                useHTML: true
            },
            type: "category",
            //categories: protocolNames,
            labels: {
                useHTML: true,
                rotation:0
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                useHTML: true
            },
            type: "category",
            opposite: true,
            //categories: protocolNames,
            labels: {
                useHTML: true,
                rotation:0
            }
        }],
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Percentage (%)'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            opposite: true
        }],

        tooltip: {
            //shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events:{
                  click: function (event) {
                       alert(event.point.name);
                       console.log(event);
                  }
            }
        }
    },
        series: [{
            name: 'Opening Balance',
            data: [{
                name: 'P1',
                y: 2 ,
                drilldown: 'P1OBINC_VM'
            }, {
                name: 'P2',
                y: 3,
                drilldown: 'P2OBINC_VM'
            }, {
                name: 'P3',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'P3OBINC_VM'
            },
            {
                name: 'P4',
                y: 2,
                drilldown: 'P4OBINC_VM'
            },
            {
                name: 'P5',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'P5OBINC_VM'
            }],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Received',
            color: '#000000',
            data: [{
                name: 'P1',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'P1RecvInc'
            }, {
                name: 'P2',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'P2RecvInc'
            }, {
                name: 'P3',
                y:2 ,
                drilldown: 'P3RecvInc'
            },{
                name: 'P4',
                y:3,
                drilldown: 'P4RecvInc'
            },{
                name: 'P5',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'P5RecvInc'
            }],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            },

        },{
            name: 'Responsed',
            color: '#90ED7D',
            data: [{
                name: 'P1',
                y: 2 ,
                drilldown: 'P1ResponsedInc'
            }, {
                name: 'P2',
                y: 1,
                drilldown: 'P2ResponsedInc'
            }, {
                name: 'P3',
                y: 3,
                drilldown: 'P3ResponsedInc'
            },{
                name: 'P4',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'P4ResponsedInc'
            },{
                name: 'P5',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'P5ResponsedInc'
            }],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            },

        },{
            name: 'Resolved',
            color: '#F7A35C',
            data: [{
                name: 'P1',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'P1ResolvedInc'
            }, {
                name: 'P2',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'P2ResolvedInc'
            }, {
                name: 'P3',
                y: 6,
                drilldown: 'P3ResolvedInc'
            },{
                name: 'P4',
                y: 6,
                drilldown: 'P4ResolvedInc'
            },{
                name: 'P5',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'P5ResolvedInc'
            }],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            },

        },{
            name: 'Carried Forward',
            color: '#0000ff',
            data: [{
                name: 'P1',
                y: 6,
                drilldown: 'P1CarriedInc'
            }, {
                name: 'P2',
                y: 2,
                drilldown: 'P2CarriedInc'
            }, {
                name: 'P3',
                y: 3,
                drilldown: 'P3CarriedInc'
            },{
                name: 'P4',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'P4CarriedInc'
            },{
                name: 'P5',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'P5CarriedInc'
            }],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            },

        },{
            name: 'Queued',
            color: '#F7A35C',
            data: [{
                name: 'P1',
                y: 12,
                drilldown: 'P1QueuedInc'
            }, {
                name: 'P2',
                y:14,
                drilldown: 'P2QueuedInc'
            }, {
                name: 'P3',
                y: 15,
                drilldown: 'P3QueuedInc'
            },{
                name: 'P4',
                y: 21,
                drilldown: 'P4QueuedInc'
            },{
                name: 'P5',
                y: 46,
                drilldown: 'P5QueuedInc'
            }],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            },

        },{
            name: 'SLA Hold',
            color: '#ffff00',
             data: [{
                name: 'P1',
                y: 3,
                drilldown: 'P1SLAInc'
            }, {
                name: 'P2',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'P2SLAInc'
            }, {
                name: 'P3',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'P3SLAInc'
            },{
                name: 'P4',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'P4SLAInc'
            },{
                name: 'P5',
                y: 6,
                drilldown: 'P5SLAInc'
            }],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            }
        }
        ],
        drilldown: {

            series: [{
                name: 'OB',
                id: 'P1OBINC_VM',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                    ['OB P1 ',12]


                ],
                Type: 'INC'
            },
            {
                name: 'OB',
                id: 'P2OBINC_VM',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                    ['OB P2 ',4]

                ],
                Type: 'INC'
            },
            {
                name: 'OB',
                id: 'P3OBINC_VM',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                    ['OB P3 ',5],


                ],
                Type: 'INC'
            },
            {
                name: 'OB',
                id: 'P4OBINC_VM',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                    ['OB P4 ',6]


                ],
                Type: 'INC'
            },
            {
                name: 'OB',
                id: 'P5OBINC_VM',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                    ['OB P5 ',5]


                ],
                Type: 'INC'
            },{
                name: 'Received',
                id: 'P1RecvInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                  ['Received P1 ',2]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },{
                name: 'Received',
                id: 'P2RecvInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                  ['Received P2 ',3]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },{
                name: 'Received',
                id: 'P3RecvInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                  ['Received P3 ',3]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },{
                name: 'Received',
                id: 'P4RecvInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                  ['Received P4 ',2]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },{
                name: 'Received',
                id: 'P5RecvInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                  ['Received P5 ',5]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            }, {
                name: 'Responsed',
                id: 'P1ResponsedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [

                    ['Responsed P1 ',6]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },{
                name: 'Responsed',
                id: 'P2ResponsedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [

                    ['Responsed P2 ',7]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },{
                name: 'Responsed',
                id: 'P3ResponsedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [

                    ['Responsed P3 ',3]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },{
                name: 'Responsed',
                id: 'P4ResponsedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [

                    ['Responsed P4 ',6]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },{
                name: 'Responsed',
                id: 'P5ResponsedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [

                    ['Responsed P5 ',7]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Resolved',
                id: 'P1ResolvedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [

                    ['Resolved P1 ',6]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Resolved',
                id: 'P2ResolvedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                    ['Resolved P2 ',7]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Resolved',
                id: 'P3ResolvedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                ['Resolved P3 ',6]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Resolved',
                id: 'P4ResolvedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [

                    ['Resolved P4 ',4]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Resolved',
                id: 'P5ResolvedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                    ['Resolved P5 ',5]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Carried Forward',
                id: 'P1CarriedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                   ['Carried P1 ',7]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },{
                name: 'Carried Forward',
                id: 'P2CarriedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                   ['Carried P2 ',8]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },{
                name: 'Carried Forward',
                id: 'P3CarriedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                   ['Carried P3 ',8]
                 ],
                 Type: 'INC'
            },{
                name: 'Carried Forward',
                id: 'P4CarriedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                   ['Carried P4 ',4]
                 ]
            },{
                name: 'Carried Forward',
                id: 'P5CarriedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                   ['Carried P5 ',6]
                 ]
            }, {
                name: 'Queued',
                id: 'P1QueuedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                   ['Queued P1 ',2]
                 ]
            },{
                name: 'Queued',
                id: 'P2QueuedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                   ['Queued P2 ',3]
                 ]
            },{
                name: 'Queued',
                id: 'P3QueuedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                   ['Queued P3 ',4]
                 ]
            },{
                name: 'Queued',
                id: 'P4QueuedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                   ['Queued P4 ',5]
                 ]
            },{
                name: 'Queued',
                id: 'P5QueuedInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                   ['Queued P5 ',6]
                 ]
            },{
                name: 'SLA Hold',
                id: 'P1SLAInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                   ['SLA Hold P1 ',7]
                 ]
            },{
                name: 'SLA Hold',
                id: 'P2SLAInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [
                   ['SLA Hold P2 ',5]
                 ]
            },{
                name: 'SLA Hold',
                id: 'P3SLAInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [

                    ['SLA Hold P3 ',4]
                 ]
            },{
                name: 'SLA Hold',
                id: 'P4SLAInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [

                    ['SLA Hold P4 ',3]
                 ]
            },{
                name: 'SLA Hold',
                id: 'P5SLAInc',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                data: [

                    ['SLA Hold P5 ',7]
                 ]
            }]
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: basically your question is drill down is not working or something else is problem. With click event what you want to get. Can you clarify

Comment: values of bar and some custom values also like type i specified in the code.

Comment: What exactly is not working? `alert(event.point.y)` will display the value of each bar. https://jsfiddle.net/j8y21axp/5/

Comment: @Stuart once you click on the P1 or P2 in the graph you can get a drill down. in the drill down have few bars, that bars values which am talking about https://jsfiddle.net/pravisivadasan/j8y21axp/4/

Comment: You can access the drilldown object via e.target.options.drilldown.series and then you can filter your series based on the point which was clicked https://jsfiddle.net/j8y21axp/6/

Comment: thanks @morganfree, its working fine.